# cant start mysql on Mac OS 10.9.2

Tags: mysql, linux, macos

I installed mysql 5.6.16 from [www.mysql.com/downloads/](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/). And it worked. But after restarting system I cant start(stop,restart) mysql. When I try start I see the error:

```
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start
mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

So tried:

```
sudo chown -R root:wheel /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
```

but it not work.
Also I cant find /etc/my.cnf
What wrong I do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788381/getting-cant-connect-through-socket-tmp-mysql-when-installing-mysql-on-m)?
Verify that there is a /tmp/mysql.sock file, and/or try mysqld_safe.